# Pandas Dataframe to JSON with Custom Encoding

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe in Pandas that looks like this:

```
associateid  c1  c2
X19          19  22
C20          55  51
```

If I use the inbuilt pandas feature to_json as records format I get the expected:

```
[
{
    "associateid":"X19",
    "c1":"19",
    "c2":"22"
},
{
    "associateid":"C20",
    "c1":"55",
    "c2":"51"
}
]
```

However, I need to run this JSON using S3's copy command, which support this strict format:

```
{
    "associateid":"X19",
    "c1":"19",
    "c2":"22"
}
{
    "associateid":0,
    "c1":"55",
    "c2":"51"
}
```

With no comma's between each record, and no surrounding [ ]  wrapper.

Can you help guide me in the best way to tackle this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible directly from pandas, but you can edit the file afterwards with python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about modifying the json string

```
s = df.to_json(orient='records')
s = s.replace( '[{','{')
s = s.replace( '},{', '}{')
s = s.replace( '}]','}')
```

and im assuming you can dump the string like this:

```
import json
outfile = open('test.json', 'w')
json.dump(s, outfile)
outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question but I think Pandas has a direct option for this now. Add "lines=True" to the parameters, like so:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'associateid':['X19','C20'],'c1':['19','55'],'c2':['22','51']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.to_json(orient='records',lines=True)
```

It puts in a line break instead of commas and also removes the brackets. Output is this:

```
'{"associateid":"X19","c1":"19","c2":"22"}\n{"associateid":"C20","c1":"55","c2":"51"}'
```